# Inserting into a table using a procedure only if the record doesn't exist yet

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a table that i'm trying to populate via a plsql script (runs on plsql developer). The actual DML statement
is contained in a procedure inside a package. The procedure only inserts if the record doesn't exist yet.

It doesn't work. The part that checks for existence returns true after the first iteration of the script loop even if it doesn't actually exist in the table.

If i put the commit outside of the loop, nothing gets inserted at all and the existence checks return true for all iteration even if the table it empty.

When i try to simplify the insert with existence check to be in just one statement without the exception handling, i get the same outcome.

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong here.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY some_package
IS
  PROCEDURE add_to_queue(id IN NUMBER)
  IS
    pending_record VARCHAR2(1);
  BEGIN
    -- this part succeeds even if nothing matches the criteria
    -- during the loop in the outside script
    SELECT 'Y'
    INTO pending_record
    FROM dual
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 'x' FROM some_queue smq
                  WHERE smq.id = id AND smq.status IS NULL);
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      INSERT INTO some_queue (seqno, id, activity_date)
      VALUES (some_sequence.nextval, id, SYSDATE);
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      NULL;
  END;
END some_package;
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE some_queue
(
  seqno             VARCHAR2(500) NOT NULL,
  id                NUMBER NOT NULL,
  activity_date     DATE NOT NULL,
  status            VARCHAR2(25),
  CONSTRAINT some_queue_pk PRIMARY KEY (seqno)
);
```

---

```
-- script to randomly fill in the table with ids from another table
declare
  type ids_coll_tt is table of number index by pls_integer;

  ids_coll_table ids_coll_tt;

  cursor ids_coll_cur is
    select tab.id
    from (select *
          from ids_source_table
          order by dbms_random.value ) tab
    where rownum < 10;
begin
  open ids_coll_cur;
  fetch ids_coll_cur bulk collect into ids_coll_table;
  close ids_coll_cur;

  for x in 1..ids_coll_table.count
  loop
    some_package.add_to_queue(ids_coll_table(x));
    commit; -- if this is here, the first iteration gets inserted
  end loop;
  -- commit; -- if the commit is done here, nothing gets inserted
end;
```

Note: I translated this code to be more generic for posting. Forgive me if there are any typos.

Update: even if i put everything inside the script and not use the package, i'm not able to properly check for existence and I get the same results.

Comment: Never do `when others then null`.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY some_package
IS
  PROCEDURE add_to_queue(p_id IN NUMBER)
  IS
    pending_record VARCHAR2(1);
  BEGIN
    -- this part succeeds even if nothing matches the criteria
    -- during the loop in the outside script
    SELECT 'Y'
    INTO pending_record
    FROM dual
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 'x' FROM some_queue smq
                  WHERE smq.id = p_id AND smq.status IS NULL);
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      INSERT INTO some_queue (seqno, id, activity_date)
      VALUES (some_sequence.nextval, p_id, SYSDATE);
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      NULL;
  END;
END some_package;
```

changing the parameter name fixed it. I guess the compiler gets confused if it's the same name as the table field.

Answer (score 0):

Don't name the parameter the same as the column (use a prefix like `p_` or `in_`) and you can do it in a single statement if you use a `MERGE` statement self-joining on the `ROWID` pseudo-column:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY some_package
IS
  PROCEDURE add_to_queue(
    in_id IN NUMBER
  )
  IS
  BEGIN
    MERGE INTO some_queue dst
    USING ( SELECT ROWID AS rid
            FROM   some_queue
            WHERE  id = in_id
            AND    status IS NULL ) src
    ON ( src.rid = dst.ROWID )
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
      INSERT (seqno,                 id,    activity_date)
      VALUES (some_sequence.nextval, in_id, SYSDATE);
  END;
END some_package;
```